# How do I complete the “shoot and miss monsters 50x” mission in Doodle Jump?

Tags: doodle-jump

I have played Doodle Jump for a while and now they have a feature called missions. One of my missions is called "shoot and miss monsters 50x". I couldn't figure out how to complete this mission. The mission bar starts filling up but then it resets itself. Any suggestions?

Comment: I assume you've already ruled out the idea of simply *deliberately missing* monsters 50 times in a row?  The name of the mission makes it sound fairly straightforward, perhaps you could elaborate on what you've tried already that hasn't worked?

Answer (score 0):

The mission requires shooting and missing monsters 50x **consecutive / in a row**

The bar was resetting probably when you were hitting one.

Answer (score 0):

It doesnt need to be 50 different monsters - you can miss the same one 50 times and pass the mission. Just bounce on the same platform near a monster for a while and fire a lot of misses!